# Error when trying to combine PassportJS and ReCAPTCHA V2. "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, recaptcha

Setting up my first ExpressJS Portfolio page, with user logins using PassportJS. I wanted to add ReCAPTCHA V2 from Google into the login process, but I'm getting an error when I combine Passport and ReCAPTCHA.

**Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

I believe the error is coming from how I set up the return next() in my POST section, but I cannot figure out why. I tried a few different configurations, and Googling answers to no avail.

If I remove the passportJS code within the POST section, The ReCAPTCHA V2 code works. I'm missing something simple surely, but I'm lost on how to get them to work together. Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** I removed my two ReCAPTCHA **V2** keys for security (site key, and secret key), they will have to be replaced by working keys from Google ReCAPTCHA **Version 2**.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MyDatabase', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    UserDetails.findOne({
      username: username
    }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      if (user.password != password) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    cb(err, user);
  });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserDetail = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});
const UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail, 'userInfo');


app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  if (
    req.body.captcha === undefined ||
    req.body.captcha === '' ||
    req.body.captcha === null

  ) {
    return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "Please select captcha" }); // If no CAPTCHA is selected / checkbox not checked
  }

  // secret key
  const secretKey = 'INSERT SECRET KEY'; // You need to add a secret key from Google ReCAPTCHA V2

  // verify URL
  const verifyUrl = `https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;

  // make request to verify url
  request(verifyUrl, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("parsed body: ", body);
    // if not successful
    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      console.log("Request verifyUrl failed");
      return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "Failed captcha vericiation" }); // if can't connect to Google and verify CAPTCHA
    }

    // line below works if passport code and next() is removed
    // return res.json({ "success": true, "msg": "captcha passed!" }); // Connected to Google and verified CAPTCHA
  });
  return next(); // Is the error coming from this?
},
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log("Passport function was called ...");
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/success');
  });

// ####################### PASSPORT


// ######################### PASSPORT END

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("SERVER STARTED on port 3000")
});
```

my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <title>Recaptcha and Passport Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Subscribe</h1>
        <form id="subscribeForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE KEY GOES HERE"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div>


    <script>
        document.getElementById('subscribeForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

        function submitForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
            const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
            const captcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;

            fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password, captcha: captcha})
            })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("Fetch data: ", data);
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To see it run without an error, remove the passport.authenticate code in the POST section, and the return next() above it. Also uncomment the return res.json success line above the next().